# C++ renaming external files

Tags: c++, visual-c++

working with W7 and visual studio. My problem today is that I can't rename external files outside my project directory. Rename() function works for local files only, tried to copy file rename it and put it back to its place, but thats not the best way to do this in my opinion. So what ways you could offer for editing (renaming, deleting and so on) external files in your computer?

Edit: Rename() mentioned above is from stdio.h library : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/rename/
I will be using this in sort of automatic file name randomizer

Comment: Show code, give some hint on where this Rename() function is from. If it is possible add GetLastError() value.

Comment: sorry, edited added more info

Comment: you should analyze what errno contains (it is the link you provided), I suppose GetLastError() should be set to error anyway. On Windows 7 with enabled UAC you might not be able to modify all files, ie. files created under c:\program files will be put under C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\VirtualStore\. Renaming files in c:\program files actually does not work (learned from own experience). You might test your app with UAC disabled to eliminate this problem at least for debuging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "rename" function from Boost.Filesystem /* http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/ */ takes path as an argument:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/reference.html#rename

See tutorial for examples:
http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/filesystem/v3/doc/tutorial.html

Comment: How do you know its Rename() from boost?

Comment: Actually, I don't think "Rename" is "rename" -- instead, I'm suggesting using the one from Boost.